# ruby on rails - create and populate combobox / dropdown from another scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display a combobox in my web page.
I have two objects :
i.e.
  rails generate scaffold person id:integer name:string
  rails generate scaffold state id:integer name:string

I want on the person to be able to choose state.
What is the best practice?
should I run a different scaffold ?
(one that will create me a foreign key in the db and another code ?)
thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to create a form that effects both models(Person, State)?

Answer (score 0):

If a `Person` can only be linked to a single `State` at any time, add a `state_id` field to `Person`. If a `Person` can have many `States` linked to it, for example, `Residences` you should create a object for that containing both the `state_id` and the `person_id`.

More on relations and linking models can be found in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

To render a dropdown list of states you can use the [select helper method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags). Make sure to use the proper field name for the select input field(state_id), instead of the name of the association.(state)